# How to Select Prony Method Order?

Tags: power, programming, math, frequency-response

I'm implementing a Prony decomposition to analyse power system signals in python. I think the code is generally working, but reconstructing a signal from the decomposition shows that it's not "perfect".

Part of the issue is that I have no idea what order I should use. Are there any rules of thumb or best practices for selecting the order? Also, how many components should be used to reconstruct a signal? I've defaulted to using `order/2`, but I've tried a number of options for both parameters, but they're all not great.

Comment: Why are you using Prony? What does that choice tell you about the data? Perhaps MUSIC or ESPRIT might be better suited if you're unsure of the order?

Comment: Neil, I'm really not sure why other than that Prony seems relatively commonly used in power system analysis. I've found using high orders (1024) seem to work ok sometimes, but other times, it seems unstable, and I get single components that are HUGE.